# Java : HttpHeaders -LinkedHashMap - ClassCastException Byte to String

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers

I have POJO which is received from redis streams. I want to retrieve the HttpHeaders from the pojo but getting below exception.

```
System.out.println("-- Request json headers Authorization : " + eventReq.getHttpHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Byte and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getFirst(HttpHeaders.java:1629)
```

POJO:

```
public class EventReq implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String EventType;
    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
    private EventFlowReq eventFlowReq;
}
```

When i am tried to debug the code, below the HttpHeaders,

[image]

I tried with `new String(eventReq.getHttpHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION))` , but still getting same exception.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because getFirst method from HttpHeaders tries to return a string, but if you look at the implementation it calls getFirst method from MultiValuedMap, which return a byte in your case.
My suggestion is to replace HttpHeaders with MultiValuedMap, call getFirst method, and only then try to cast it to a string.